# sql query only reads the first number of the ID

Tags: php, sql

Hi I have created a website that allows you to download videos you can specify what videos you want using drop down boxes. there are five drop down boxes subject section and principle and then seperatley there are job role and career. the selection boxes are connected to each other for example if you select english in the subject box it only shows the sections connected to english subject and the same with principle it will only show the principles related to the section. my problem at the moment is when choose the job role and careers which values should be (1, 15) actually return the results (1,1) which says there are no results related to them. my full sql query code is:

`

```
<?php
class SelectList
{
    protected $conn;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->DbConnect();
        }

        protected function DbConnect()
        {
            include "db_config.php";
            $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
            mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
            return TRUE;
        }

        public function ShowCategory()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT subject_id,description FROM subject";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $category = '<option value="%">Subject</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $category .= '<option value="' . $row['subject_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $category;
        }

        public function ShowType()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT section_id,description FROM section WHERE subject_id=$_POST[id]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $type = '<option value="%">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $type .= '<option value="' . $row['section_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $type;
        }

         public function ShowPrinciple()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT principle_id,description FROM principle WHERE section_id=$_POST[id]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $principle = '<option value="%">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $principle .= '<option value="' . $row['principle_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $principle;
        }

        public function GetResults()
        { 
        $vars = $_POST["comboboxselections"]; // this gets comboboxselections from index.php


           $box = ""; // placeholder for the html results to be returned to 
           $sql = "SELECT title,blurb FROM media WHERE subject_id = $vars[0] AND section_id= $vars[1] AND principle_id= $vars[2] "; // sql query 
           $box = $sql;

           $hasprintedrecords = false; // capture records if there are no records printed to screen 
           //$box .= $sql;
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn); // connection to database and also getting the results from query
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) // the loop while there are results within the array run the function
            {
                $hasprintedrecords = true;// if there are records this equals true if not equals false 
                $box .= '<div style=";height:120px;"id=\"Video\"><br/><div style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#00000;width:504px;float:right;"id=\"Title\">'.$row['title'].'</div> <div style="width:220px;height:100px;float:left;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;" id=\"VideoImage\">hii</div> <div style="height:50px;width:504px;float:right;padding:2px;margin-bottom:5px;" id=\"Blurb\">'.$row['blurb'].'</div><div style="height:21px;width:152px;background:url(images/bg_top_img2-09.jpg) repeat-x;color:#ffffff;padding-left:2px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;position:relative;border-radius:15px;text-align:center;" id=\"Downloads\"> Download </div></div>'; // if results are available then display to screen 
            }
            if ( $hasprintedrecords == false) // if there are no results then function below is run  
            { 
            $box .='<div id=\"video\" style=\" border-style:solid; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px;\"> <div style="border-style:dashed; border-color:#f90;" id="text"> no media found for this selection.</div></div>'; // returns html message to screen 
            }
            return $box; // returns results to the screen
        }

        public function ShowJobRole() { 

        $sql = "SELECT jobrole_id,description FROM jobrole";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $jobrole = '<option value="%">Job role</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $jobrole .= '<option value="' . $row['jobrole_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $jobrole;
        } 


        public function ShowCareer() { 


        $sql = "SELECT career_id,description FROM career WHERE jobrole_id=$_POST[id]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $career = '<option value="%">Career</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $career .= '<option value="' . $row['career_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $career;
        } 



        public function get_job () { 
        $vars1 = $_POST["comboboxselections1"]; // this gets comboboxselections from index.php

            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);


           $box = ""; // placeholder for the html results to be returned to 
           $sql = "SELECT title,blurb FROM media_career_crossref INNER JOIN media ON media.media_id = media_career_crossref.media_id WHERE media_career_crossref.jobrole_id = $vars1[0] AND media_career_crossref.career_id = $vars1[1] ";
           $box = $sql;

           $hasprintedrecords = false; // capture records if there are no records printed to screen 
           //$box = $sql;
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn); // connection to database and also getting the results from query
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) // the loop while there are results within the array run the function
            {
                $hasprintedrecords = true;// if there are records this equals true if not equals false 
                $box .= '<div style=";height:120px;"id=\"Video\"><br/><div style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#00000;width:504px;float:right;"id=\"Title\">'.$row['title'].'</div> <div style="width:220px;height:100px;float:left;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;" id=\"VideoImage\">hii</div> <div style="height:50px;width:504px;float:right;padding:2px;margin-bottom:5px;" id=\"Blurb\">'.$row['blurb'].'</div><div style="height:21px;width:152px;background:url(images/bg_top_img2-09.jpg) repeat-x;color:#ffffff;padding-left:2px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;position:relative;border-radius:15px;text-align:center;" id=\"Downloads\"> Download </div></div>'; // if results are available then display to screen 
            }
            if ( $hasprintedrecords == false) // if there are no results then function below is run  
            { 
            $box .='<div id=\"video\" style=\" border-style:solid; border-color:#000000; border-width:1px;\"> <div style="border-style:dashed; border-color:#f90;" id="text"> no media found for this selection.</div></div>'; // returns html message to screen 
            }
            return $box; // returns results to the screen


        } 
        }
$opt = new SelectList();
?>
```

and the javascript and html that are the drop down boxes are:

```
<html>
    <head>

            <!--[if !IE]><!-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content.css">
            <!--<![endif]-->

            <!--[if IE 7]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE7Content.css" />
            <![endif]-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#category").change(function(){
                $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#type").html(data);
            });
        });
        $("select#principle").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#type").change(function(){
                $("select#principle").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#principle").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                var id = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("select_principle.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#principle").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#principle").html(data);
            });
        });

                $("select#career").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#jobrole").change(function(){
                $("select#career").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#career").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                var id = $("select#jobrole option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("select_career.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#career").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#career").html(data);
            });
        });

        $("form#select_form").submit(function()
        {
            var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
            var princ = $("select#principle option:selected").attr('value');
                $txt = cat + type + princ;
                var id = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("get_results.php", {comboboxselections:$txt}, function(data){
                $("#Results").html(''+data);
            });
            if(cat>0 && type>0 && princ>0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose three options!");
            }
            return false;
        });

        $("form#select_job").submit(function(){
            var job = $("select#jobrole option:selected").attr('value');
            var car = $("select#career option:selected").attr('value');
                $txt1 = job + car;
                var id = $("select#career option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("get_jobresults.php", {comboboxselections1:$txt1}, function(data){
                $("#Results").html(''+data);
            });         
            if(job>0 && car>0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
            }
            return false;
        });
        });
</script>   
<body>
    <?php
        $host=""; // Host name
        $username=""; // Mysql username
        $password=""; // Mysql password
        $db_name=""; // Database name
        $tbl_name=""; // Table name

        session_start();
        $_SESSION["username"];
        $_SESSION["password"];
        $_SESSION["access"];
    ?>
    <div id="Container">
        <div id="Header">
            <div id="SignIn"> <!-- This is the SignIn -->
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> <!-- This is the Logout button -->
                <a href="login.php">Login</a> <!-- This is the Login button -->
                <a href="index.php">Home</a> <!-- This is the Home button --> 
            </div><!-- This is the end of SignIn -->
            <div id="MainNavigation">

                <a href="content.php"><img id="button2" src="images/banner2new.jpg"></a></li>  
                <a href="contributors.php"><img id="button1" src="images/banner3new.jpg"></a> 


            </div><!-- End of the MainNavigation -->
        </div> <!-- End of the Header -->
        <div id="Content">

            <?php
            $Public = "Please Login in or register an account to be able to see the content";               
            if($_SESSION["username"] == "")
            {   
                      header("Location: http://thor/classroom/login.php");
            }

            if($_SESSION["access"] == "Consumer")
            {
                echo "<div id=\"Options\">";
                include "select.class.php"; 
                echo "<form id=\"select_form\">";
                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">"; 
                echo "Choose a subject:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\" id=\"category\" name=\"cat\" >";
                echo $opt->ShowCategory();
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a section:";
                echo "</div>";              
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"type\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "Section";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a principle:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"principle\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "Principle";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<input style=\"margin-left:10px;\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Search\"/>";
                echo "</form>";

                echo " ------ Or ------";


                echo "<form id=\"select_job\">";
                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";

                echo "Choose a Job Role:";
                echo "</div>";              
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"jobrole\">";
                echo $opt ->ShowJobRole();
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a career:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"career\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "career";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<input style=\"margin-left:10px;\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Search\"/>";
                echo "</form>";
                echo "</div>"; // end of the options tag any new content that needs to be on left side put inside this tag
                echo "<div id=\"Results\">";
                echo "</div>"; // end of the results results div needs to be out of the options tag
            }

                if($_SESSION["access"] == "Contributor")
            {
                echo "<div id=\"Options\">";
                include "select.class.php"; 
                echo "<form id=\"select_form\">";
                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">"; 
                echo "Choose a subject:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\" id=\"category\" name=\"cat\" >";
                echo $opt->ShowCategory();
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a section:";
                echo "</div>";              
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"type\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "Section";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a principle:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"principle\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "Principle";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<input style=\"margin-left:10px;\" type=\"submit\" value=\"confirm\"/>";
                echo "</form>";

                echo "<form id=\"select_job\">";
                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a Job Role:";
                echo "</div>";              
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"jobrole\">";
                echo $opt ->ShowJobRole();
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a career:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"career\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "career";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<input style=\"margin-left:10px;\" type=\"submit\" value=\"confirm\"/>";
                echo "</form>";
                echo "</div>"; // end of the otions tag any new content that needs to be on left side put inside this tag
                echo "<div id=\"Results\">";
                echo "</div>"; // end of the results results div needs to be out of the otions tag
            }

                if($_SESSION["access"] == "Administrator")
            {
                echo "<div id=\"Options\">";
                include "select.class.php"; 
                echo "<form id=\"select_form\">";
                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">"; 
                echo "Choose a subject:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\" id=\"category\" name=\"cat\" >";
                echo $opt->ShowCategory();
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a section:";
                echo "</div>";              
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"type\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "Section";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a principle:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"principle\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "Principle";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<input style=\"margin-left:10px;\" type=\"submit\" value=\"confirm\"/>";
                echo "</form>";

                echo "<form id=\"select_job\">";
                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a Job Role:";
                echo "</div>";              
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"jobrole\">";
                echo $opt ->ShowJobRole();
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";

                echo "<div class=\"selecttitle\">";
                echo "Choose a career:";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"career\">";
                echo "<option value=\"%\">";
                echo "career";
                echo "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<input style=\"margin-left:10px;\" type=\"submit\" value=\"confirm\"/>";
                echo "</form>";
                echo "</div>"; // end of the otions tag any new content that needs to be on left side put inside this tag
                echo "<div id=\"Results\">";
                echo "</div>"; // end of the results results div needs to be out of the otions tag
            }
            ?>  
        </div> <!-- End of the Content -->
        <!-- <div id="SignIn">
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                <a href="login.php">Login</a>
                <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </div> -->
    </div> <!-- End of the Container -->
</body> <!-- End of the Body -->
</html> <!-- End of the Html -->`
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that populates `$vars1`?

Comment: do a print_r on vars1

Comment: @Mihai I have printed the $vars1[1] and it shows as 1 instead of 15

Comment: So the problem is in the generation of those values.

Comment: @Pattle the drop down boxes use sql queries to get the values then they are posted to find the media related to that value the sql query for $vars1[1] is: 
`$sql = "SELECT career_id,description FROM career WHERE jobrole_id=$_POST[id]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $career = '<option value="%">Career</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $career .= '<option value="' . $row['career_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $career;
  } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump($vars);`
var_dump or similar print_r is your friend in situations like this to determine whethere the array has the structure you want and contain the proper data.

if `$vars1` containing only single array then you should use fetchall to push the datas gathered by your query

```
$sql = "SELECT career_id,description FROM career WHERE jobrole_id={$_POST[id]}";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $all[] = $row;
        }
        return $all;
    }
```

you got 
`jobrole_id = $_POST['id']` and

```
carear_id = $all[0]['carear_id']
```

Note: I highly suggest you to to use PDO, because your code is very open to sql injections thru post[id];

Furter editing;

```
        public function ShowCareer() { 

        $sql = "SELECT career_id,description FROM career WHERE jobrole_id=$_POST[id]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $career = '<option value="%">Career</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $career .= '<option value="' . $row['career_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $career;
        }
```

so the problem is with this code ? am i correct? below is the expected result up to 15?

```
<option value="1">Career 1</option>
<option value="2">Career 2</option>
<option value="3">Career 3</option>
```

an so on?
and by the way 
try fixing `$_POST[id]` to `{$_POST['id']}`

if you database structure is like

**Jobrole:(parent)**

```
*jobrole_id* | description
```

**Career (child)**

```
career_id | *job_id* | description
```

So you want to use the *Jobrole* table's *id* inside the *career* *job_id*
i assume your {$_POST['id']} is holding Jobrole_id then change your code above like this

```
    public function ShowCareer() { 


    $sql = "SELECT career_id,description FROM career WHERE job_id={$_POST['id']}";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $career = '<option value="%">Career</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $career .= '<option value="' . $row['career_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $career;
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand how it would pull down singular data because when it uses the id's then it works fine until it gets to 10 and above it only reads the first number. but the thing is i have text been brought to the screen and the whole sentence is brought to the screen

Comment: the second drop down box no longer gets populated from the database

Comment: You have to provide your all of the codes related to your question because your drop down box sounds gybberish to me without knowing its context. Be more  specific.

Comment: yes the value for those options when they get to double figures it only shows the first digit so if its 15 then it will only show 1 if it is 50 then it will only show 5

Comment: try fixing $_POST[id] to {$_POST['id']}

Comment: i have changed that and with your first example it still does not populate the second drop down but with my original code it works but still does not display numbers past nine @Oğuzhan Pişkin

Comment: But you know that you have to have 15 different datas with the same jobrole_id=$_POST['id'] to pull 15 different datas right! if you only have 1 data with the id=1 for example  you would only get 1 result. But assume you got 5 data with the jobrole_id=1 then you would pull 5 of them

Comment: i have a table for careers and a table for jobroles in the careers there are 100 pieces of data with an id from 1 to 100 and then in the job role i have 400 jobs related to the career they have and id from 1 to 400 it is a primary into total i have about 4 job roles for each career and yes that is what i am trying to do when you pick the career and the job role i want all media related to these which may be from 1 - 10 videos and this is what i would like to show on the screen

Comment: Buddy this not a code problem, what you want is related to your database structure and you probably want to use Inner joins to merge two tables to get results You want to pick an 'id' from career and an 'id' for a jobrole you got ids like career_id and jobrole_id and use them in your SQL query. Whats your database structure? Database Relation is important thats what you need to look up here..

Comment: my database structure is very simple, my career tables columns are career_id, job_id, Description and my jobrole table columns are jobrole_id, description. the id in both tables are auto increment and they are both INT(11) that is it the career table is the parent to jobrole table thats all tbh. there is nothing other than that really in between the two tables nothing else is related to these tables

Comment: this didn't work, it populates the drop down box but it still posts the number 1 instead of 15

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what i had done wrong it wasn't a problem with the sql it was a problem with the javascript at the top because at the top all of the data from the database is put together i just completely forgot that i had to split them to form the correct answer so in the database it would be 2,10,11 when it gets put together it would look like 21011 and then when the drop down boxes read this it reads the 2 then the 1 instead of the 10

thanks for the suggestions.